# how to access C++ class data member from C function

Tags: c++, c

assuming there is a C++ class defined as follow,

```
/* goo.h */
#ifdef __cplusplus
class goo{
public:
    vector<int> a;
    vector<int> b;
    void calc();
};
#else
typedef struct goo goo;
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {

#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
void goo_calc(goo *);
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

then i want to implement `goo::calc()` in C, so i write following codes.

```
/* goo_cpp.cpp */
#include "goo.h"
void goo::calc(){
    goo_calc(this);
}

/* goo_c.c */
#include "goo.h"
void goo_calc(goo *g){
    /* do something with g->a and g->b */
}
```

but `gcc` says `goo has no fields named a and b`, so what's wrong?

---

UPDATE:

Supposing `vector<int> a` is replaced by `int a[3]`, and `vector<int> b` is replaced by `int b[3]`.

Is this correct to access `goo->a` and `goo->b` from C function?

Comment: "do something with g->a and g->b": that won't be C code. Since a and b are C++ vectors...

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement `goo_calc` in a C++ translation unit, with C language linkage.

```
// goo_cpp.cpp
extern "C" void goo_calc(goo *g){
    /* do something with g->a and g->b */
}
```

No other way to use a C++ type other than in a C++ translation unit.